# Python patching __new__ method

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I am trying to patch `__new__` method of a class, and it is not working as I expect.

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager

class A:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        print('A init', arg)

@contextmanager
def patch_a():
    new = A.__new__

    def fake_new(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print('call fake_new')
        return new(cls, *args, **kwargs) 
        # here I get error: TypeError: object.__new__() takes exactly one argument (the type to instantiate)

    A.__new__ = fake_new
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        A.__new__ = new

if __name__ == '__main__':
    A('foo')
    with patch_a():
        A('bar')
    A('baz')
```

I expect the following output:

```
A init foo
call fake_new
A init bar
A init baz
```

But after `call fake_new` I get an error (see comment in the code).
For me It seems like I just decorate a `__new__` method and propagate all args unchanged.
It doesn't work and the reason is obscure for me.

Also I can write `return new(cls)` and call `A('bar')` works fine. But then `A('baz')` breaks.

Can someone explain what is going on?

<sup>Python version is 3.8</sup>

Comment: `A.__new__ is object.__new__` which only takes a single argument. You should call it simply as `new(cls)`. I don't understand why the call with `'baz'` is failing.... strange...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've run into a complicated part of Python object instantiation - in which the language opted for a design that would allow one to create a custom `__init__` method with parameters, without having to touch `__new__`.

However, the in the base of class hierarchy, `object`, both `__new__` and `__init__` take one single parameter each.

IIRC, it goes this way: if your class have a custom `__init__` and you did not touch `__new__` and there are more any parameters to the class instantiation that would be passed to both `__init__` and `__new__`, the parameters will be stripped from the call do `__new__`, so you don't have to customize it just to swallow the parameters you consume in `__init__`. The converse is also true: if your class have a custom `__new__` with extra parameters, and no custom `__init__`, these are not passed to `object.__init__`.

With your design, Python sees a custom  `__new__` and passes it the same extra arguments that are passed to `__init__` - and by using `*args, **kw`, you forward those to `object.__new__` which accepts a single parameter - and you get the error you presented us.

The fix is to not pass those extra parameters to the original `__new__` method - unless they are needed there - so you have to make the same check Python's type does when initiating an object.

And an interesting surprise to top it: while making the example work, I found out that *even if `A.__new__`
is deleted* when restoring the patch, it is still considered as "touched" by cPython's `type` instantiation, and the arguments are passed through.
In order to get your code working I needed to leave a permanent stub `A.__new__` that will forward only the `cls` argument:

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager

class A:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        print('A init', arg)

@contextmanager
def patch_a():
    new = A.__new__

    def fake_new(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print('call fake_new')
        if new is object.__new__:
            return new(cls)
        return new(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        # here I get error: TypeError: object.__new__() takes exactly one argument (the type to instantiate)

    A.__new__ = fake_new
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        del A.__new__
        if new is not object.__new__:
            A.__new__ = new
        else:
            A.__new__ = lambda cls, *args, **kw: object.__new__(cls)

        print(A.__new__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    A('foo')
    with patch_a():
        A('bar')
    A('baz')
```

(I tried inspecting the original `__new__` signature instead of the `new is object.__new__` comparison - to no avail: `object.__new__` signature is `*args, **kwargs` - possibly made so that it will never fail on static checking)

Comment: I added `def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs): return super().__new__(cls)` to `class A` and everythong worked. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, so since `A.__new__` has been touched, it is considered "custom" even though it's the original `__new__`? Man, that's unexpected

Comment: @Rugnar so, I think, an alternative approach is to not save the reference to `A.__new__` and then re-assign it to `A.__new__` at the end of the context-manager, instead, just directly call `object.__new__`.  Not sure which I prefer

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga In my case I will need multiple nested patches of the same object. So that calling object.__new__ will not work for me.

Comment: @jsbueno it actually makes sense if I think about it, the way it is considered "touched" is if there exists *any* `__new__` in the `A` namespace. Originally, it's simply inheriting from `object`, but when you "unpatch" it, it is now in a new namespace (indeed, it is in both namespaces). Something to that effect

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga : yes, it is considered touched, **even if it is deleted back**. I found it out while meddling with the code example.  That is certainly peculiar.

Comment: @jsbueno that's *really* surprising. I wonder what the actual mechanism is.